# Exchange Online hybrid migration rollback

Tags: exchange-2013, exchangeonline, exchange-migration

I need to recover a failed Exchange Online hybrid migration from a single Exchange 2013 server. All changes were backed out, however obvious artifacts remain that demonstrate this is not the case.

1. Creating new mailboxes on Exchange 2013 using EAC/ECP still creates a @example.mail.onmicrosoft.com ProxyAddress for the new mailbox (where our domain is example.com in this example).
2. Users randomly being asked by Outlook 2016 to authenticate (which fails); this began during the migration and continues to occur, generally (but not always) corresponding with a network status change on the client.

These are two obvious artifacts, but I am not sure what has been rolled-back and what needs to be done still.

How can I determine what remains to be cleaned up?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Exchange Server 2013 has been end of life since April 2013 and is off topic for this forum. You should have been off 2013 *years* ago. Knowing that you have a product that is marooned, it is a good idea to have good backups and recovery procedures and test them. Additionally, migrations such as this should be top heavy in risk assessment and mitigation of risk, and contingencies for backout. You don't have that. That valuable lesson is one take away from this disaster. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/exchange-2013-end-of-support

Comment: 2023, not 2013. the EOL date. But still, EOL.

Comment: The @example.mail.onmicrosoft.com ProxyAddress appears to be related to Email Address Policy created when running the HCW. Check and reconfigure the Email address policy accordingly.

Comment: How did you do migration? Using a PowerShell script or the wizard?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Creating new mailboxes on Exchange 2013 using EAC/ECP still creates a @example.mail.onmicrosoft.com ProxyAddress for the new mailbox
>    (where our domain is example.com in this example).

You need to remove the Exchange Hybrid configuration.

> 2. Users randomly being asked by Outlook 2016 to authenticate (which fails); this began during the migration and continues to occur,
>    generally (but not always) corresponding with a network status change
>    on the client.

You need to make sure your autodiscover record in DNS is correct and you need to make sure the Exchange Service Connection Point in AD is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here are high level steps. In case you need some elaboration let me know

1. Remove Migration Batches
2. Cancel Mailbox Moves
3. Remove Federation Trust

   Remove-FederationTrust -Identity "Microsoft Federation Gateway"

   Remove-FederationTrust -Identity "Microsoft Federation Agreements"
4. Revert AutoDiscover Configuration (Verify AutoDiscover configuration on the on-premises Exchange server. If any changes were made, revert them to the previous settings) .
5. Revert Accepted Domains
6. Revert Send and Receive Connectors:
7. Validate Mail Flow

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it is very helpful in recovery from a failed migration by a service provider. I've validated against the steps you've supplied. One question, there is still some evidence of the migration in our configuration. For example. `Get-HybridConfiguration` returns an object of class `msExchCoexistenceRelationship` (also reflected in **EAC > hybrid** showing a "modify" button). Also, `Get-OrganizationRelationship` returns an object of class `msExchFedSharingRelationship`. Would you say these should be removed, or leave until we re-attempt migration.

Comment: I think with a new run of the Exhange HCW those will be overwritten.